# showing the value of last cell in textview when using excel

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is my code:

```
 textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
 textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            AssetManager am = getAssets();
            InputStream is = am.open("Book1.xls");
            try {
                Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
                Sheet s = wb.getSheet(0);
                int row = s.getRows();
                int col = s.getColumns();
                String xx = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                    for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
                        Cell z = s.getCell(c,i);
                        xx = z.getContents();
                        //xx = xx + "\n";
                        textView.setText(xx);
                    }
                    //xx = xx + "\n";
                }
                //textView.setText(xx);
            } catch (BiffException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
   });
```

When I run this code it shows me the value of only last cell in the output for example if i have used 4 cell in my excel sheet but output will be shown the value of last cell.

Comment: That's not quite right, the text is set to each one of the cell values, but overridden in the next iteration step. What do you want to achieve? Concatenating all the cell values and show the result in the `TextView`?

Comment: I want to display all the values of excel file in my output.

Comment: Then create a `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();` and `append()` the cell values in every iteration. Then after the loops, set the text by `textView.setText(sb.toString());`.

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration, you are setting the textview, so, your previous values are being replace. You might try append instead of setText.

Also, `s.getCell(c,i)` should be `s.getCell(i,c)`

Comment: Thank you i have used append method but s.getCell(c,i) cannot be changed.

Comment: @MadhusudanPandey if it solves the problem, consider accepting it as the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

textView.append(xx);//this the code which i have changed